# Problems with project paths in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, path

Im having problems moving my SSIS Projects to a new PC.

At the moment I have all my Projects in
C:\Documents and Settings\myname\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects

But my .dtsx packages are located in a different folder. This folder does not exist on my new pc. So whenever I try open the projects on my new PC It complains it cant find the path etc which makes sense. So what I am trying to do is save my .dtsx packages back within the project folder.

My Issue is I cant figure out how to change to Path of the .dtsx files when I open the project and right click on properties of the .dtsx file the path is greyed out and non-editable. If i go to save dtsx file as...and point to new folder it saves and updates the grey path but then when i open the project again it reverts back to the old path.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the project file in a text editor and edit the paths to your .dtsx files first, then open the project file by double clicking it, it will load the .dtsx files from the path specified in your project file.

Answer (score 0):

If your dtsx file upper case changed to lower case then Rename Your dtsx file again to any other name and build it..It will work definitely.